# VirtualBox : Windows Server RT 2008 can't ping RHEL6 and vice versa

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ping

I have three VMs in my VB

- RHEL6 IPv4 : 192.168.43.202(Static)
  Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
  Gateway: 192.168.0.1
- RHEL6 IPv4 : 192.168.43.201(Static)
  Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
  Gateway: 192.168.0.1
- Win RT 2008 IPv4 : 192.168.43.203(Static)
  Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
  Gateway: 192.168.0.1

All three are in Bridged Networking.

I can ping  202 and 201, i.e., both the RHELs can ping,
but I could not ping Win RT from RHEL and vice versa.

```
:Destination Host Unreachable
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I had my Ethernet adapters name different. I selected the same adapter for all three VMs and now It is working fine.